# c++ if statement with a return outside of the block

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is a duplicate post as I don't even know the right words to use to search for it.

I can across some c++ code that looks like this:

```
void start()
{
  if (call(initialize())) return;
  {
    // the rest of the code runs here
  }
  terminate();
}
```

Am I missing something or is this just code obfuscation by somebody who hates everyone else who have to read this code?

Comment: "_is this just code obfuscation by somebody who hates everyone else who have to read this code?_" Depends on the code inside said block. For instance: One may be certain that destructors, of objects, be called at the end of the block, before the `terminate` call.

Comment: @Michael Nguyen Maybe after the if the keyword else followed that then was deleted.:)

Comment: I agree with @AlgirdasPreidžius, this scopes the objects inside the block so they're correctly destructed before `terminate()`. However, the formatting is definitely misleading.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev: In programming, the line between laziness and hating your fellow developers is... thin. Intent notwithstanding, one tends to lead to the other.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, biggest disasters are often done with good intentions.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev: Ah, but "good" is subjective ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree, one lazy programmer saving 1 minute of work may equal hours of other people's time figuring what is the intention.  Like here I am asking this question on SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something

Not really, no.

> is this just code obfuscation by somebody who hates everyone else who have to read this code?

That, or it's a mistake (e.g. missing `else`, or the `return;` shouldn't be there).

*If* the code in the block really needs to be in a block (which is certainly not impossible — this is a common way to control scope), then it should at least be preceded by a blank link to make clear that it has nothing to do with the `if` statement.

The code might be better written like this:

```
void start()
{
   if (call(initialize()))
      return;

   {
      // stuff in a block
   }

   terminate();
}
```

Even here I would almost certainly include a proper comment inside the block scope, both to explain *why* it was necessary (if not self-evident) and to in turn implicitly re-assure that it's not some accidental misformatting of an `if`/`else` chain.